# Laravel Driver error - Driver [] is not supported

Tags: php, laravel

Anyone else had this issue:

I set my filesystems.php config `defualt` from `local` to `cloud` (which is set to my s3) and I get this error with my storage code:

`$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');` -> in my UserController

Error : `Driver [] is not supported.`

If I leave the filesystems config to stock and just run this code the image uploads to my s3 fine

`$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 's3');` -> in my UserController

shouldnt `$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');` run to what ever the default is without passing the specific driver? I tried `'default' => 's3',` and that gets the same error

CONFIG DRIVERS

```
'default' => 'local',
'cloud' => 's3',
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that whether your example with manually typing a storage to the store() function works well, you can have a problem with storage config.
Could you, please, show your configuration file with storage types?

Comment: Ya, the `$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 's3');` successfully uploads to my S3 bucket. I will add my config, but I figured since that works it wasnt a config issue or my env file